# Twilio AU1/sydney video api endpoint?

Tags: node.js, typescript, twilio, twilio-api

I'm following the guide [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/global-infrastructure/using-the-twilio-rest-api-in-a-non-us-region) about creating a twilio endpoint, which from my understanding for the video api would be: `https://video.sydney.au1.twilio.com/`

However that URL does not exist, it's the same URL the twilio client tries to hit when I create the client with:

```
        const client = twilio.default('sid', 'tokem', {
            region: 'au1',
            edge: 'sydney',
        });
```

My API region is set to Australia so authentication fails if I keep the default video.twilio.com URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like au1 is not supported for the video api so have to use the US API for video.